# EFAULT when trying to send char

Tags: c++, linux, debian, send, raw-sockets

I am trying to send a single 1 byte value using `send` however when I try to it fails and sets `errno` to `EFAULT`. I am unsure why this is as I am setting the `buf` argument to the address of the char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define INVALID_SOCKET ~0

int main()
{
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
    struct sockaddr_in sin = {0};
    char C0 = 3;

    if(s == INVALID_SOCKET){exit(1);}

    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(/*ip*/);
    sin.sin_port        = htons(1935);
    sin.sin_family      = AF_INET;

    printf("Destination IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr));
    printf("Destination Port: %u\n", ntohs(sin.sin_port));

    if(connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin)) == -1){printf("Errno: %d\n", errno);exit(2);}

    if(send(s, &C0, 1, 0) == -1)
    {
        switch(errno)
        {
            case EFAULT:
            {
                printf("Error: Invalid memory address\nExiting\n");
                close(s);
                exit(3);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                printf("Error: %d\nExiting\n", errno);
                close(s);
                exit(3);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, you actually pass the wrong size to the `connect` call. It should be the size of the actual socket address structure you use, in your case `sizeof sin`.

Comment: On a possibly more related note, you should probably clear the whole `sin` structure. Like e.g. `struct sockaddr_in sin = { 0 };`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Noted. Thank you!

Comment: Why should I zero out `sin`?

Comment: I've found that if I set `C0` to 0 then it succeeds. It's only if it's set to any other value.

Comment: @J.Doe Maybe the buffer needs to be null-terminated, with the size including the terminating character?

Comment: @tambre I have already attempted this but it still returned `EFAULT`.

Comment: On yet another note: The `socket` call return `-1` if it fails, just like the other calls. So `INVALID_SOCKET` should be `-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a *raw* socket. That means you have to create the full IP packet from scratch to send, which you do not do.

What happens right now is *undefined behavior* as the `send` call and the underlying network stack goes out of bounds reading data beyond the single byte you provide.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. I was curious as to why sometimes it would return `EINVAL` or `EFAULT`. But I think I understand now. I am trying to initiate a RTMP handshake, which yes I know requires C1 as well, and for whatever reason I completely forgot to make the ip header.